# vga to usb monitor cable duel monitors on laptop

Tags: usb, vga

my VGA port stopped working on my laptop. i got a VGA to usb wire any way to use it? i plugged it in screen comes on then goes to standby. running Ubuntu 14.04 any ideas or do i need a special wire to do that

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check the VGA cable itself as it is more common that it's the cable what is broken and not the port.

What type of adapter is it? Male VGA / Female USB ? 
Is the monitor a USB monitor?

If your laptop is relatively modern (5 years or newer) chances are there is a HDMI port, this would be a better option AFAIK.

If your monitor is USB it should work with a common USB cord.

Comment: its a old monitor and laptop. monitor is VGA only. i tried different cables didn't work before it stopped working i had to wiggle the wire to get it to come on so thats why i thin its the port. for the usb wire its male so i can plug right into my laptop

Comment: If the monitor is able to use USB it should work out of the box... however, it has to be a proper USB monitor, there are some monitors with an USB hub but this is not meant to transmit image data but just to add extra ports to the computer. 
In any case it's safe to try.

Another option would be to use the laptop's monitor as an external monitor: http://www.instructables.com/id/Laptop-Converted-to-2nd-Monitor/